# How to exclude root elements in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have several elements defined in my XSD file that I use as references later on in the document.  I do want any of these "reference" elements to constitute a valid xml file.

For example I have

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Section">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="code"/>
            <xs:attribute name="url"/>
            <xs:attribute name="isLegacy"/>
            <xs:attribute name="name"/>
            <xs:attribute name="helpFileName"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Sections">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I don't want the following xml to validate (if this is the only line in the file)

```
<Section code="" url="" isLegacy="" name="" helpFileName="" />
```

Removing the "Section" node from the global prevents me from referencing it for recursion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that, don't declare these elements as global, instead, base your schema design on complex types and declare only the element you want as a root global. Nobody forces you to make every element global.

For example, your sample can be refactored as follows:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Section">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Section" type="Section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="code"/>
        <xs:attribute name="url"/>
        <xs:attribute name="isLegacy"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
        <xs:attribute name="helpFileName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Sections">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Section" type="Section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: edited original post to provide a better example of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: using xmlspy to validate that xsd, I still get the same problem of when you say ref="Section", it bitches that "'Section' must refer to an existing element".  Anyway around that?

Comment: Oops; editing mistake, I removed that element reference and replaced it with a local element. n.b. you might want to read up on xml schema complex types, it's worth your time!

Comment: excellent, that worked exactly how I wanted to. Thanks very much for the prompt and numerous responses!